# Dynamic Linq - String.Split

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

It appears that Dynamic Linq doesn't implement the String.Split method.

Is there a way achieve the same results with Dynamic Linq ?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic Linq does support String.Split and also calling other .net type methods as shown below

```
var query =
                db.Customers.Where("City.Split(\"abc\".ToCharArray()).Length == 1 and Orders.Count >= @1", "London", 10).
                OrderBy("CompanyName").
                Select("New(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

It was able to convert the string to expression tree but as SQL doesn't have any string split operation it throws error if you run it on SQL

Answer (score 0):

Answer to comment below:

```
string teststring = "one, two, three";

var x = from string z in (teststring.Split(',').AsEnumerable())
where z.Trim() == "two"
select z;
```

What exactly do you want to do?  The following works just fine in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

```
from z in ("4,3,5,2,1".Split(',').AsEnumerable())
  select z
```

---

Comment: // how do I evaluate this in Dynamic Linq to find if it contains the substring 'two' ?
string teststring = "(\"one, two, three\".Split(','))";

Comment: Review this to understand the context of my question.  http://aspalliance.com/1569_Dynamic_LINQ_Part_1_Using_the_LINQ_Dynamic_Query_Library

Comment: If you have an IQueryable collection there are better ways to dynamically compose expressions: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: @ljm : From the link I see what you mean.  If you post code that you want to work using that library I might be able to show you a work-around.