# Using Linq, how do I query for records matching a comma-separated list of IDs?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a comma-separated list of record Ids that I get from a query string. I need to return all the records (from a SQL Server database) with those Ids. What's the best way to do that in Linq?

I figure that it will ultimately be transformed into a SQL statement of the form "WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...)", and since that query contains the same comma-separated list that I'm starting with, it seems a shame to un-pack it into an int array and then let Linq convert it back again. But if that's the only way, then fine.

Comment: It is a good idea to convert it to an array anyway, to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you hinted at, it's easiest to convert it to an array first.

```
string csv = "1,2,3";
IEnumerable<int> ids = csv.Split(',').Select( str => int.Parse(str));

var records = db.Records.Where( rec => ids.Contains(rec.id) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Dynamic Linq to avoid the unnecesary conversion

```
.Where("MyColumn.Contains(@0)", myArray)
```

[Dynamic Linq - String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127781/dynamic-linq-string-split)

[How to use "contains" or "like" in a dynamic linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455659/how-to-use-contains-or-like-in-a-dynamic-linq-query)