# Parsing text file containing hierarchical items using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm rewriting some code and trying to use Linq whenever I can. My problem right now is a simple file import function.

The file basically looks like this:

```
A1
B1|1882
C1|7315808907578
B9
B1|1883
C1|4025595431639
C1|8717734091786
C1|8717734091809
C1|8717734098280
C1|8717795041874
C1|8717795060998
C1|8717795108973
B9
B1|1884
C1|4025595732071
C1|7315808887184
C1|8717734001983
B9
A9
```

The existing code looks like this:

```
line = reader.ReadLine();
string itemNo = "";
List<AltItems> list = new List<AltItems>();
while (line != null) {
    posts = line.Split(postSep);
    if (posts.Length == 0) { }
    else if (posts[0].Equals("A1")) { }
    else if (posts[0].Equals("B1"))
        itemNo = posts[1];
    else if (posts[0].Equals("C1")) {
        string altItemNo = posts[1];
        list.Add(new AltItems() { ItemNo = itemNo, AltItemNo = altItemNo });
    }
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

What would the equivalent Linq query look like? Any thoughts about performance penalties rewriting this code using Linq? I also have files with multiple  hierarchical levels where data from items on the first level is needed to build up items on the third level...

Comment: The "hierarchical" part is not clear. But LINQ is not the best tool if you need to access a different index of a collections during enumeration.

Comment: just because the code works does not mean you should convert everything to LINQ - makes no sense to. LINQ really was designed for database languages and the programming languages to kind of make some form of sense when writing it in LINQ. I am NOT saying LINQ is a DB language which executes on the .NET framework. you would get the same perf and output as you are right now.

Comment: Since you need to carry context forward (`itemNo`, `altItemNo`) it is unlikely you can get nice looking LINQ statement. Consider using Aggregate as it designed to carry context during iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Ahmed ilyas. Rewriting everything in LINQ does not mean it would work faster.

Especially, regarding string parsing, you should know that it is not supported in LINQ. This is absolutely reasonable if you think that LINQ is a **query language targeting data sources of many kinds in a unified way**. There are ways to do it, but they are always too indirect and I don't particularly like them. One of them, is using Scott Guthry's [DynamicLinq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library, the way it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127781/dynamic-linq-string-split).

Please note that I only show you a way to do string parsing using LINQ. **This does not mean that I would suggest using LINQ to replace conditional code.**

Hope I helped!